# Discrepancies between Matlab and Numpy matrix inverse

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix

I have been able to find a few bug reports, but no conclusive answer or solution to what I'm seeing. I have a working Matlab script that builds a matrix and extracts values from its inverse. It is working and the plots agree with the theory.

I started moving the program over to Python to try some other libraries, but it's not working as expected. I've logged all of the values found for the matrix both in Matlab and Python, and they agree. However, it seems to break down on the calculation of the inverse. Neither regular, pseudo, or .I inverses in numpy are giving the correct answer. Since every value used until then is the same in both scripts, I was thinking this had to come down to a problem with numpy's linalg.inv(). I have some old files for finding inverses, but can't imagine whatever horror I whipped up will outdo the internal implementations. Has anyone faced a similar problem and have an idea of where to  go? Thank you!

Edit: Code below. I'm finding the reflection/transmission for a bandpass filter, with the end goal of inserting non-infinite transmission zeros with cross-couplings and optimizing the mismatches it introduces.

I marked the spots where it all breaks down.

1) Python Code:

```
def s_from_m(n, ripple, w0, bw, bw_is_hz, tz_freq):

    # Get cheby low-pass prototype values for resistance matrix.
    g_vals = cheby_g_vals(n, ripple)
    m = np.floor(n/2)

    # Use center frequency and bandwidth to find passband edges
    if bw_is_hz:
        w1 = w0 - bw/2
        w2 = w0 + bw/2
        # Modified center frequency.
        w0 = w1 + w2 - np.sqrt( (w2-w1)**2 + w1*w2 )
    else:
        # Solve for needed w1/w2 using quadratic formula.
        w1 = (-bw*w0 + np.sqrt( (bw*w0)**2 + 4*(w0**2) )) / 2
        w2 = (w0**2)/w1

    # Fractional Bandwidth for cross-coupling calculations.
    fbw = (w2 - w1) / w0

    # Source and load external quality coefficients
    q_source = (g_vals[0]*g_vals[1]) / fbw
    q_load = (g_vals[-1]*g_vals[-2]) / fbw

    # Build resistance, frequency, and coupling matrices.
    R = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.complex)
    R[0,0] = 1/q_source
    R[n-1,n-1] = 1/q_load
    S = np.eye(n)
    M = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.complex)

    # Calculate direct-coupling coefficients
    for i in range(1, n):
        M[i-1, i] = fbw/np.sqrt(g_vals[i]*g_vals[i+1])
        M[i, i-1] = M[i-1, i]

    # Cross-coupling coeff for given ratio
    m1 = tz_freq/w0 
    M[m-1,m+1] = -m1
    M[m+1,m-1] = -m1

    # Range 8 bandwidths wide in total for visualization.
    w_range = np.arange(w1-4*bw, w2+4*bw, (w2-w1)/10000)
    x = len(w_range)

    # Stores S11 and S21 with current coeffs.
    s11 = np.zeros(x)
    s21 = np.zeros(x)

    A = np.matrix(R + S - 1j*M)

    # Populate s11/s21 based on admittance/impedance matrix
    for j in range(x):
        # A = np.matrix(R + 1j*(w_range[j]/w0 - w0/w_range[j])*S - 1j*M)
        # Only modify the values being changed.
        np.fill_diagonal(A, 1j*(w_range[j]/w0 - w0/w_range[j]))
        A[0,0] += 1/q_source
        A[-1,-1] += 1/q_load
        # EVERYTHING UNTIL THIS POINT AGREES WITH MATLAB
        inv_a = A.I
        s11[j] = 1 - (2/q_load)*inv_a[0,0]
        s21[j] = (2/np.sqrt(q_source*q_load))*inv_a[n-1,0]

    # Convert to dB
    s11 = 20*np.log10(abs(s11))
    s21 = 20*np.log10(abs(s21))
```

Python Logs:

```
Chebyshev g vals: [ 1.      1.7373  1.2582  2.6383  1.3443 2.6383  1.2582  1.7373  1.    ]

Overall coupling matrix:

[ 0.      0.0271  0.      0.      0.      0.      0.    ] 
[ 0.0271  0.      0.022   0.      0.      0.      0.    ]
[ 0.      0.022   0.      0.0213  0.      0.      0.    ]
[ 0.      0.      0.0213  0.      0.0213  0.      0.    ]
[ 0.      0.      0.      0.0213  0.      0.022   0.    ]
[ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.022   0.      0.0271] 
[ 0.      0.      0.      0.      0.      0.0271  0.    ]
```

2) Matlab Code

```
function [A, M, S21, S11, w] = SfromM(nIn, ripLevel, w0In, BW, bwInHz, tzFreq)
 %% Function to generate S parameters for a bandpass filter.
 % Use a Chebyshev response for prototype values, then create the coupling coefficients. 
 % Overall resistance matrix built up of real resistances, frequency
 % components, and coupling coefficients. This matrix is then inverted, and the appropriate 
 % formulas used to create S11 and S21. 
 % nIn is filter order. 
 % ripLevel is max ripple allowed in Passband.
 % w0In is input center frequency. 
 % BW is bandwidth in Hz or percent
 % bwInHz is flag value to handle both Hz and percent bandwidth inputs.
 % tzFreq is frequency for cross-coupling zero (Hz)

% Chebyshev and filter parameters
g = gVals(nIn, ripLevel);
n = nIn;
m = floor(n/2);

% Center frequency and bandwidth used to find edges of passband.
if bwInHz % BW given in Hz (w2-w1)
    w1 = w0In - BW/2;
    w2 = w0In + BW/2;
    w0 = w1 + w2 - sqrt( (w2-w1)^2 + w1*w2 );
    FBW = (w2-w1)/w0;
else % BW given in percent (w2-w1)/w0
    w0 = w0In;
    w1 = (-(BW*w0In) + sqrt( (BW*w0In)^2 + 4*(w0In^2) )) / 2;
    w2 = w0In^2/w1;
    FBW = (w2 - w1)/w0;
end


% Source and load external quality coefficients.
qSource = (g(1)*g(2))/FBW;
qLoad = (g(n+1)*g(n+2))/FBW;

% Building resistance, frequency, and coupling matrices.
R = zeros(n);
R(1,1) = 1/qSource;
R(n,n) = 1/qLoad;
S = eye(n);
M = zeros(n);

% Calculating direct-coupling coefficients
% display('Coefficients founds as FBW / sqrt(g(i)*g(i+1))');
for i = 2:n
    M(i-1, i) = FBW/sqrt(g(i)*g(i+1));
    M(i, i-1) = M(i-1, i); % Filling lower diagonal with same coupling
end

% Cross coupling coefficients from given ratio
% m1 = (tzFreq)/w0;
% M(m,m+2) = -m1;
% M(m+2,m) = -m1;

% Different frequency values for plotting:
w = 4*10^9:10^6:6*10^9; % for 5 Ghz in Mhz steps.
x = length(w);

% % For storing regular values.
S21 = zeros(1,x);
S11 = zeros(1,x);


% Generate S21 and S11 response from admittance/impendace matrix.
for s = 1:x
    % Definition of overall impedance matrix.
    A = (R + 1i*(w(s)/w0 - w0/w(s))*S - 1i*M);
    # Works fine.
    inva = inv(A);
    % Conversion to S parameters with external quality coefficients.
    S21(s) = (2/sqrt(qSource*qLoad))*inva(n,1);
    S11(s) = 1 - (2/qLoad)*inva(1,1);
end

% Convert to dB again
S11 = 20*log10(abs(S11));
S21 = 20*log10(abs(S21));
```

Matlab Logs:

```
g values for n = 7, and rip level = 0.5:

g = 

    1.0000   1.7373   1.2582   2.6383   1.3443   2.6383   1.2582   1.7373   1.0000

         0   0.0271        0        0        0        0        0
    0.0271        0   0.0220        0        0        0        0
         0   0.0220        0   0.0213        0        0        0
         0        0   0.0213        0   0.0213        0        0
         0        0        0   0.0213        0   0.0220        0
         0        0        0        0   0.0220        0   0.0271
         0        0        0        0        0   0.0271        0
```

EDIT 2: Still working on the example.
While I chip at it, it does seem like the calculation of s11/s21 and/or 20*log10() operation is to blame. Matrices A and inv_a are the same for Python and Matlab. However, calculating s21 and s11 with the formulas, then taking the 20*log10() power, the answers drastically change. Anyone see a silly mistake around that area I'm blind to? Thanks!

Comment: The probability, that there is an error in `linalg.inv` is very low. It's much more likely, that there is some mistake in your code. Please show your matlab and python code with an example matrix, so we can help you.

Comment: I agree with that too, but I've verified everything with logs and the values until that point are the same. The only spot where it's breaking down is the inverse calculation. If it helps, I can add plots too. The Matlab output is smooth, while the numpy output has some crazy spikes that look more like asymptotes than anything. I purposefully made the Python code as similar as I could to the Matlab one.

Comment: you surely meant to write `%` instead of `#` in the third last line of your Matlab code, didn't you?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, it's my first time actually posting on SO, but that shouldn't have slipped by.

Comment: A MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.  In your python logs, you show a real-valued matrix under "Overall coupling matrix", but I don't think you show the actual array `A` that you are inverting.   Without runnable code or actual output showing `A`, we have no way of checking your result.  Also, have you tried making the python code even closer to the matlab code by computing `A` with the same single line used in matlab, instead of using `fill_diagonal` and incrementing the corners?

Comment: I think that's a great idea! Thank you. I'll start chipping at it right now, with a basic example. I was thinking of storing and comparing the S21 / S11 values from the scripts as well, to see the difference there.