# Inverse matrix results different in MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix, inversion

I am trying to convert my program from MATLAB to Python. Everything seems to work fine until I try to invert one of my matrices (22x22). I get different values for the inverse matrix. In MATLAB I have used the function `inv(J)` and also `A\b` to invert the matrix, while in python I have used `J.I` and also `np.linalg.inv(J)`. While both functions in python return the same result, they are different from from what I get in MATLAB. Even the determinant values are different for the two cases. While MATLAB returns a value in the order of 10^23, python returns a value of 10^20. Is it possible for a matrix to have more than one inverse? Or does it have anything to do with the precision of the calculation?

There is a similar discussion in this thread: 
[Discrepancies between Matlab and Numpy matrix inverse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39434302/discrepancies-between-matlab-and-numpy-matrix-inverse).
However, I did not find any conclusive answer in that discussion and hence I am posting it again.

Edit: The matrix is not very well conditioned.

Here is the python program:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cmath
import math
from decimal import *
from pandas import DataFrame

ldata = '''\
   1    2  1  1 1 0  0.01938   0.05917     0.0528     0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   1    5  1  1 1 0  0.05403   0.22304     0.0492     0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   2    3  1  1 1 0  0.04699   0.19797     0.0438     0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   2    4  1  1 1 0  0.05811   0.17632     0.0340     0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   2    5  1  1 1 0  0.05695   0.17388     0.0346     0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   3    4  1  1 1 0  0.06701   0.17103     0.0128     0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   4    5  1  1 1 0  0.01335   0.04211     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   4    7  1  1 1 0  0.0       0.20912     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.978     0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   4    9  1  1 1 0  0.0       0.55618     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.969     0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   5    6  1  1 1 0  0.0       0.25202     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.932     0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   6   11  1  1 1 0  0.09498   0.19890     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   6   12  1  1 1 0  0.12291   0.25581     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   6   13  1  1 1 0  0.06615   0.13027     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   7    8  1  1 1 0  0.0       0.17615     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   7    9  1  1 1 0  0.0       0.11001     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   9   10  1  1 1 0  0.03181   0.08450     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
   9   14  1  1 1 0  0.12711   0.27038     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
  10   11  1  1 1 0  0.08205   0.19207     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
  12   13  1  1 1 0  0.22092   0.19988     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
  13   14  1  1 1 0  0.17093   0.34802     0.0        0     0     0    0 0  0.0       0.0 0.0    0.0     0.0    0.0   0.0
  '''
line = pd.compat.StringIO(ldata)
df = pd.read_csv(line, sep='\s+', header=None)
linedata = df.values

nbus = 14

fb = (linedata[:,0]) #from bus
fb = fb.astype(int)
tb = (linedata[:,1]) #to bus
tb = tb.astype(int)
r = linedata[:,6] #resistence
x = linedata[:,7] #reactance
b = (linedata[:,8])/2 #b/2
b = 1j*b
a = linedata[:,14] #transformer ratio
#change the 0s to 1s for the transformer tap changing ratio
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 0:
        a[i] = 1
z = r + 1j*x
y = 1/z
nb = int(max(max(fb),max(tb)))
#print(max(tb))
nl = len(fb)
#print(nl)
Y = np.zeros((nb,nb))
Y = Y + 1j*Y
#forming the off-diagonal elements
for k in range(nl):
    Y[fb[k]-1,tb[k]-1] = (Y[fb[k]-1,tb[k]-1]) - (y[k]/a[k])
    Y[tb[k]-1,fb[k]-1] = Y[fb[k]-1,tb[k]-1]

#forming the diagonal elements
for n in range(nl):
        Y[fb[n]-1,fb[n]-1] = Y[fb[n]-1,fb[n]-1]+(y[n]/(a[n]*a[n]))+b[n]
        #elif tb[n]==m:
        Y[tb[n]-1,tb[n]-1]=Y[tb[n]-1,tb[n]-1]+((y[n])+b[n])
#print(Y)

bdata = '''\
   1 Bus 1     HV  1  1  3 1.060    0.0      0.0      0.0       0        0     0.0  1.060     0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
   2 Bus 2     HV  1  1  2 1.045  -4.98     21.7     12.7     40.0    42.4     0.0  1.045    50.0   -40.0   0.0    0.0        0
   3 Bus 3     HV  1  1  2 1.010 -12.72     94.2     19.0      0.0    23.4     0.0  1.010    40.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
   4 Bus 4     HV  1  1  0 1.019 -10.33     47.8     -3.9      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
   5 Bus 5     HV  1  1  0 1.020  -8.78      7.6      1.6      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
   6 Bus 6     LV  1  1  2 1.070 -14.22     11.2      7.5      0.0    12.2     0.0  1.070    24.0    -6.0   0.0    0.0        0
   7 Bus 7     ZV  1  1  0 1.062 -13.37      0.0      0.0      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
   8 Bus 8     TV  1  1  2 1.090 -13.36      0.0      0.0      0.0    17.4     0.0  1.090    24.0    -6.0   0.0    0.0        0
   9 Bus 9     LV  1  1  0 1.056 -14.94     29.5     16.6      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.19       0
  10 Bus 10    LV  1  1  0 1.051 -15.10      9.0      5.8      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
  11 Bus 11    LV  1  1  0 1.057 -14.79      3.5      1.8      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
  12 Bus 12    LV  1  1  0 1.055 -15.07      6.1      1.6      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
  13 Bus 13    LV  1  1  0 1.050 -15.16     13.5      5.8      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
  14 Bus 14    LV  1  1  0 1.036 -16.04     14.9      5.0      0.0     0.0     0.0  0.0       0.0     0.0   0.0    0.0        0
  '''
busd = pd.compat.StringIO(bdata)
dfbus = pd.read_csv(busd, sep='\s+', header=None)
dfbus = dfbus.loc[:,dfbus.dtypes != 'object']
busdata = dfbus.values

#print(busdata)
BMva = 100
bus = busdata[:,1]
type = busdata[:,4]
for i in range(len(type)):
    if type[i] == 3:
        type[i] = 1
    elif type[i] == 0:
        type[i] = 3

V = busdata[:,12]
for i in range(len(V)):
    if V[i] == 0:
        V[i] = 1

delta = busdata[:,15]
Pg = busdata[:,9]/BMva
Qg = busdata[:,10]/BMva
Pl = busdata[:,7]/BMva
Ql = busdata[:,8]/BMva
Qmin = busdata[:,14]/BMva
Qmax = busdata[:,13]/BMva
P = Pg - Pl
Q = Qg - Ql
Psp = P
Qsp = Q
#print(Qsp)

G = Y.real
B = Y.imag
pq = np.where(type == 3)
npq = len(pq[0])
pv = np.where(type < 3)
npv = len(pv[0])
Tol = 1
Iter = 1

while Tol > 1e-5:
    P = np.zeros(nbus)
    Q = np.zeros(nbus)
    #Calculate P and Q
    for i in range(nbus):
        for k in range(nbus):
            P[i] = P[i] + V[i]*V[k]*(G[i,k]*np.cos(delta[i]-delta[k]) + B[i,k]*np.sin(delta[i]-delta[k]))
            Q[i] = Q[i] + V[i]*V[k]*(G[i,k]*np.sin(delta[i]-delta[k]) - B[i,k]*np.cos(delta[i]-delta[k]))

    #Calculate the change from the specified value
    dPa = Psp - P
    dQa = Qsp - Q
    k = 0
    dQ = np.zeros(npq)
    for i in range(nbus):
        if type[i] == 3:
            dQ[k] = dQa[i]
            k = k + 1
    dP = dPa[1:nbus]
    #print(dP)
    M = np.concatenate((dP,dQ))

    #Jacobian Matrix formation
    #J1-Derivative of real power injections with angles
    J1 = np.zeros((nbus-1,nbus-1))
    for i in range(nbus-1):
        m = i + 1
        for k in range(nbus-1):
            n = k + 1
            if n == m:
                for n in range(nbus):
                    J1[i,k] = J1[i,k] + V[m]*V[n]*(-G[m,n]*np.sin(delta[m]-delta[n])+B[m,n]*np.cos(delta[m]-delta[n]))
                J1[i,k] = J1[i,k] - (V[m]**2)*B[m,m]
            else:
                J1[i,k] = V[m]*V[n]*(G[m,n]*np.sin(delta[m]-delta[n])-B[m,n]*np.cos(delta[m]-delta[n]))
    #J2 = Derivative of real power injections with V
    J2 = np.zeros((nbus-1,npq))
    for i in range(nbus-1):
        m = i +1
        for k in range(npq):
            n = pq[0][k]
            #print(n)
            if n == m:
                for n in range(nbus):
                    J2[i,k] = J2[i,k] + V[n]*(G[m,n]*np.cos(delta[m]-delta[n])+B[m,n]*np.sin(delta[m]-delta[n]))
                J2[i,k] = J2[i,k] - V[m]*G[m,m]
            else:
                J2[i,k] = V[m]*(G[m,n]*np.cos(delta[m]-delta[n])+B[m,n]*np.sin(delta[m]-delta[n]))
    #J3 = derivative of Reactive Power Injections with Angles
    J3 = np.zeros((npq,nbus-1))
    for i in range(npq):
        m = pq[0][i]
        for k in range(nbus-1):
            n = k + 1
            if n == m:
                for n in range(nbus):
                    J3[i,k] = J3[i,k] + V[m]*V[n]*(G[m,n]*np.cos(delta[m]-delta[n])+B[m,n]*np.sin(delta[m]-delta[n]))
                J3[i,k] = J3[i,k] - (V[m]**2)*G[m,m]
            else:
                J3[i,k] = V[m]*V[n]*(-G[m,n]*np.cos(delta[m]-delta[n])-B[m,n]*np.sin(delta[m]-delta[n]))
    #J4 = Derivative of Reactive Power Injections with V
    J4 = np.zeros((npq,npq))
    for i in range(npq):
        m = pq[0][i]
        for k in range(npq):
            n = pq[0][k]
            if n == m:
                for n in range(nbus):
                    J4[i,k] = J4[i,k] + V[n]*(G[m,n]*np.sin(delta[m]-delta[n])-B[m,n]*np.cos(delta[m]-delta[n]))
                J4[i,k] = J4[i,k] - V[m]*B[m,m]
            else:
                J4[i,k] = V[m]*(G[m,n]*np.sin(delta[m]-delta[n])-B[m,n]*np.cos(delta[m]-delta[n]))

    Jtemp1 = np.concatenate((J1,J3))
    Jtemp2 = np.concatenate((J2,J4))
    J = np.concatenate((Jtemp1,Jtemp2),axis=1)
    #Jinvc = getMatrixInverse(J)
    X = np.linalg.solve(J,M)
    print(X)
    dTh = X[0,0:nbus-1]
    #print(dTh)
    dV = X[0,nbus-1:2*npq+npv-1]
    print(dV[0,8])
    delta[1:nbus] = dTh + delta[1:nbus]
    k = 0
    for i in range(1,nbus):
        if type[i] == 3:
            V[i] = dV[0,k] + V[i]
            k = k + 1

    Iter = Iter + 1
    Tol = max(abs(M))

print(V)
```

This is the MATLAB code:

```matlab
nbus = 14;                  % IEEE-14, IEEE-30, IEEE-57..
Y = ybusppg(nbus);          % Calling ybusppg.m to get Y-Bus Matrix..
busd = busdatas(nbus);      % Calling busdatas..
BMva = 100;                 % Base MVA..
bus = busd(:,1);            % Bus Number..
type = busd(:,2);           % Type of Bus 1-Slack, 2-PV, 3-PQ..
V = busd(:,3);              % Specified Voltage..
del = busd(:,4);            % Voltage Angle..
Pg = busd(:,5)/BMva;        % PGi..
Qg = busd(:,6)/BMva;        % QGi..
Pl = busd(:,7)/BMva;        % PLi..
Ql = busd(:,8)/BMva;        % QLi..
Qmin = busd(:,9)/BMva;      % Minimum Reactive Power Limit..
Qmax = busd(:,10)/BMva;     % Maximum Reactive Power Limit..
P = Pg - Pl;                % Pi = PGi - PLi..
Q = Qg - Ql;                % Qi = QGi - QLi..
Psp = P;                    % P Specified..
Qsp = Q;                    % Q Specified..
G = real(Y);                % Conductance matrix..
B = imag(Y);                % Susceptance matrix..

pv = find(type == 2 | type == 1);   % PV Buses..
pq = find(type == 3);               % PQ Buses..
npv = length(pv);                   % No. of PV buses..
npq = length(pq);                   % No. of PQ buses..

Tol = 1;  
Iter = 1;
while (Tol > 1e-5)   % Iteration starting..

    P = zeros(nbus,1);
    Q = zeros(nbus,1);
    % Calculate P and Q
    for i = 1:nbus
        for k = 1:nbus
            P(i) = P(i) + V(i)* V(k)*(G(i,k)*cos(del(i)-del(k)) + B(i,k)*sin(del(i)-del(k)));
            Q(i) = Q(i) + V(i)* V(k)*(G(i,k)*sin(del(i)-del(k)) - B(i,k)*cos(del(i)-del(k)));
        end
    end

    % Checking Q-limit violations..
    if Iter <= 7 && Iter > 2    % Only checked up to 7th iterations..
        for n = 2:nbus
            if type(n) == 2
                QG = Q(n)+Ql(n);
                if QG < Qmin(n)
                    V(n) = V(n) + 0.01;
                elseif QG > Qmax(n)
                    V(n) = V(n) - 0.01;
                end
            end
         end
    end

    % Calculate change from specified value
    dPa = Psp-P;
    dQa = Qsp-Q;
    k = 1;
    dQ = zeros(npq,1);
    for i = 1:nbus
        if type(i) == 3
            dQ(k,1) = dQa(i);
            k = k+1;
        end
    end
    dP = dPa(2:nbus);
    M = [dP; dQ];       % Mismatch Vector

    % Jacobian
    % J1 - Derivative of Real Power Injections with Angles..
    J1 = zeros(nbus-1,nbus-1);
    for i = 1:(nbus-1)
        m = i+1;
        for k = 1:(nbus-1)
            n = k+1;
            if n == m
                for n = 1:nbus
                    J1(i,k) = J1(i,k) + V(m)* V(n)*(-G(m,n)*sin(del(m)-del(n)) + B(m,n)*cos(del(m)-del(n)));
                end
                J1(i,k) = J1(i,k) - V(m)^2*B(m,m);
            else
                J1(i,k) = V(m)* V(n)*(G(m,n)*sin(del(m)-del(n)) - B(m,n)*cos(del(m)-del(n)));
            end
        end
    end

    % J2 - Derivative of Real Power Injections with V..
    J2 = zeros(nbus-1,npq);
    for i = 1:(nbus-1)
        m = i+1;
        for k = 1:npq
            n = pq(k);
            if n == m
                for n = 1:nbus
                    J2(i,k) = J2(i,k) + V(n)*(G(m,n)*cos(del(m)-del(n)) + B(m,n)*sin(del(m)-del(n)));
                end
                J2(i,k) = J2(i,k) + V(m)*G(m,m);
            else
                J2(i,k) = V(m)*(G(m,n)*cos(del(m)-del(n)) + B(m,n)*sin(del(m)-del(n)));
            end
        end
    end

    % J3 - Derivative of Reactive Power Injections with Angles..
    J3 = zeros(npq,nbus-1);
    for i = 1:npq
        m = pq(i);
        for k = 1:(nbus-1)
            n = k+1;
            if n == m
                for n = 1:nbus
                    J3(i,k) = J3(i,k) + V(m)* V(n)*(G(m,n)*cos(del(m)-del(n)) + B(m,n)*sin(del(m)-del(n)));
                end
                J3(i,k) = J3(i,k) - V(m)^2*G(m,m);
            else
                J3(i,k) = V(m)* V(n)*(-G(m,n)*cos(del(m)-del(n)) - B(m,n)*sin(del(m)-del(n)));
            end
        end
    end

    % J4 - Derivative of Reactive Power Injections with V..
    J4 = zeros(npq,npq);
    for i = 1:npq
        m = pq(i);
        for k = 1:npq
            n = pq(k);
            if n == m
                for n = 1:nbus
                    J4(i,k) = J4(i,k) + V(n)*(G(m,n)*sin(del(m)-del(n)) - B(m,n)*cos(del(m)-del(n)));
                end
                J4(i,k) = J4(i,k) - V(m)*B(m,m);
            else
                J4(i,k) = V(m)*(G(m,n)*sin(del(m)-del(n)) - B(m,n)*cos(del(m)-del(n)));
            end
        end
    end

    J = [J1 J2; J3 J4];     % Jacobian Matrix..
    condJ = cond(J)
    detJ = det(J);
    X = J\M;% Correction Vector
    dTh = X(1:nbus-1);      % Change in Voltage Angle..
    dV = X(nbus:end);       % Change in Voltage Magnitude..

    % Updating State Vectors..
    del(2:nbus) = dTh + del(2:nbus);    % Voltage Angle..
    k = 1;
    for i = 2:nbus
        if type(i) == 3
            V(i) = dV(k) + V(i);        % Voltage Magnitude..
            k = k+1;
        end
    end

    Iter = Iter + 1;
    Tol = max(abs(M));                  % Tolerance..

end
```

The ybusppg function:

```matlab
function Y = ybusppg(num)  % Returns Y

linedata = linedatas(num);      % Calling Linedatas...
fb = linedata(:,1);             % From bus number...
tb = linedata(:,2);             % To bus number...
r = linedata(:,3);              % Resistance, R...
x = linedata(:,4);              % Reactance, X...
b = linedata(:,5);              % Ground Admittance, B/2...
a = linedata(:,6);              % Tap setting value..
z = r + i*x;                    % z matrix...
y = 1./z;                       % To get inverse of each element...
b = i*b;                        % Make B imaginary...

nb = max(max(fb),max(tb));      % No. of buses...
nl = length(fb);                % No. of branches...
Y = zeros(nb,nb);               % Initialise YBus...

 % Formation of the Off Diagonal Elements...
 for k = 1:nl
     Y(fb(k),tb(k)) = Y(fb(k),tb(k)) - y(k)/a(k);
     Y(tb(k),fb(k)) = Y(fb(k),tb(k));
 end

 % Formation of Diagonal Elements....
 for m = 1:nb
     for n = 1:nl
         if fb(n) == m
             Y(m,m) = Y(m,m) + y(n)/(a(n)^2) + b(n);
         elseif tb(n) == m
             Y(m,m) = Y(m,m) + y(n) + b(n);
         end
     end
 end
 %Y;                  % Bus Admittance Matrix
 %Z = inv(Y);
```

The linedata function:

```matlab
function linedt = linedatas(num)

%         |  From |  To   |   R     |   X     |     B/2  |  X'mer  |
%         |  Bus  | Bus   |  pu     |  pu     |     pu   | TAP (a) |
linedat14 = [1      2       0.01938   0.05917    0.0264         1
             1      5       0.05403   0.22304    0.0246         1
             2      3       0.04699   0.19797    0.0219         1
             2      4       0.05811   0.17632    0.0170         1
             2      5       0.05695   0.17388    0.0173         1
             3      4       0.06701   0.17103    0.0064         1
             4      5       0.01335   0.04211    0.0            1
             4      7       0.0       0.20912    0.0        0.978
             4      9       0.0       0.55618    0.0        0.969
             5      6       0.0       0.25202    0.0        0.932
             6     11       0.09498   0.19890    0.0            1
             6     12       0.12291   0.25581    0.0            1
             6     13       0.06615   0.13027    0.0            1
             7      8       0.0       0.17615    0.0            1
             7      9       0.0       0.11001    0.0            1
             9     10       0.03181   0.08450    0.0            1
             9     14       0.12711   0.27038    0.0            1
            10     11       0.08205   0.19207    0.0            1
            12     13       0.22092   0.19988    0.0            1
            13     14       0.17093   0.34802    0.0            1 ];
    switch num
        case 14
            linedt = linedat14;
    end
```

The bus data function:

```matlab
function busdt = busdatas(num)

% Type....
% 1 - Slack Bus..
% 2 - PV Bus..
% 3 - PQ Bus..

%         |Bus | Type | Vsp | theta | PGi | QGi | PLi | QLi |  Qmin | Qmax |
busdat14 = [1     1    1.060   0       0     0     0     0       0       0;
            2     2    1.045   0      40   42.4  21.7   12.7    -40     50;
            3     2    1.010   0       0   23.4  94.2   19.0     0      40;
            4     3    1.0     0       0     0   47.8   -3.9     0       0;
            5     3    1.0     0       0     0    7.6    1.6     0       0;
            6     2    1.070   0       0   12.2  11.2    7.5    -6      24;
            7     3    1.0     0       0     0    0.0    0.0     0       0;
            8     2    1.090   0       0   17.4   0.0    0.0    -6      24;
            9     3    1.0     0       0     0   29.5   16.6     0       0;
            10    3    1.0     0       0     0    9.0    5.8     0       0;
            11    3    1.0     0       0     0    3.5    1.8     0       0;
            12    3    1.0     0       0     0    6.1    1.6     0       0;
            13    3    1.0     0       0     0   13.5    5.8     0       0;
            14    3    1.0     0       0     0   14.9    5.0     0       0;];
switch num
    case 14
        busdt = busdat14;
end
```

Comment: You never want to invert a matrix. Very very rarely. `inv` is a bad choice. Just use `A\b` instead of `inv(A)*b`. This happens because you have a badly conditioned matrix.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I did that. Returns the same result as the inv function.

Comment: I also do not think that MATLAB is giving me incorrect results, because the algorithm converges for the MATLAB program and the results support the theory. However, the python program does not converge due to the anomaly in the inversion process.

Comment: Yeah. Because you should never do `inv` *in a computer*, I did not  mean in a specific programming language. Use `numpy.linalg.solve` for numpy.

Comment: What is the condition number of the matrix?  Use `cond(A)` in Matlab, and `np.linalg.cond(A)` in Python with Numpy.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I tried `numpy.linalg.solve` according to your advise but it unfortunately returns the same result that I got with using `inv`. :(

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The condition number returned by MATLAB is `113.3328`, while in python it is `3948.1338`.

Comment: Are you sure the input matrices are exactly the same in Matlab and Python?  Can you post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @gaurav then it is not the same matrix.

Comment: Sure. I will edit my question to include a minimal complete and verifiable example.

Comment: Hope the matrix helps.

Comment: Well, it is displayed in an awkward format.  It is not in a form that someone can copy and paste to get into their own code or interactive shell.   It looks like you did `print(A)`.  Instead, you could do `np.set_printoptions(precision=16); print(repr(A))` to get something that displays the values with full precision and can be copied and pasted into a Python script or interactive shell.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Thanks for the suggestion. I have done it and posted the matrix again.

Comment: Also, we still need to know that the arrays are the same in Python and in Matlab.  If they are not the same, we'll just waste time experimenting with the matrix that you have shown.  Is the matrix generated with code?  If so, show the Matlab and Python code that you use.  (Simplify it as much as possible.)

Comment: Also, for the python program, try not to use the while loop, as the program is not converging. If you can compare the two matrices for the first iteration only, that would be fine.

Comment: Fixed it. I have all posted everything you need for the matlab program.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am interested in the matrix J.

Answer (score 2):

No a matrix cannot have more than one inverse but it can have no inverse, mathematically.

But all calculations on a computer are carried out with finite floating point representations and various kinds of inaccuracies that can occur at every step of the calculation.

The result of numerically inverting a matrix depends on how "well-conditioned" the matrix is. 
Even if a matrix can be inverted, if it is not well conditioned, then small changes in the input can cause large changes in the output. Since the values in a matrix are represented by finite floating point representations, just slightly different internal representations can cause big differences. Also, because all calculations are performed by finite floating point representations, the details of the algorithm used can cause differences with an ill-conditioned matrix.

Answer (score 1):

A little more detailed answer:
When the matrix is not well-conditioned, that means it has some very small eigenvalues. Let's use Singular Value Decomposition, if your matrix is `X=L @ S @ R.T`, then the inverse is `Xi=R @ np.sqrt(S) @ L.T`. Now the middle part is inversing the eigenvalues and if there are some very small ones, the floating point error can have a huge difference in their inverse and thus the difference you are seeing there.

But does it matter? No, if your matrix is not well-conditioned then the inverse you are calculating is not reliable, you can test this by multiplying it by your original matrix and see that not every element is close to identity matrix.

What is the solution?
1. Use a preconditioner
2. If you see a big change in the eigenvalues of your original matrix, simply throw those unimportant eigenvalues and eigenvectors away, reconstruct your matrix and then your inverse should be the same regardless of the platform/package/OS you are using.
Note that the first approach is basically doing the same thing as the second, just different math steps.